# Logout seems to be very buggy in Firefox and IE

Tags: facebook, logout

In Chrome and Safari it works beautifully, right when you click on the button it logs out every time.

However with FF and IE you click it on it and it just keeps on refreshing trying to load things from facebook but never goes into the logout callback. If you do it like 20 times it will finally log you out and allow you to login again. It is not consistent at all. This was all working fine some days ago, didn't change anything but now it is busted.

No Javascript Errors. Here is my log out code.

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
        {
            alert("inResponse");
            if(response.status == 'connected')
            {
                alert("inConnected");
                FB.logout(function(response){
                    alert("inLogout");
                  window.location="./logout.php";
                });
            }
     ........
```

inReponse is printing, inConnected is printing, inLogout never gets successfully called... This is very frustrating, any idea what could be wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking i'm not sure ether but i think you might be missing a few closing brackets

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response))
    {
        alert("inResponse");
        if(response.status == 'connected')
        {
            alert("inConnected");
            FB.logout(function(response)){
                alert("inLogout");
              window.location="./logout.php";
            });
        }
```

Might be helpfull